# WinAmp-Style task-bar Buttons using VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I would like to have a similar look and feel to the task-bar buttons WinAmp provides:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this before, but a bit of googling this seems to be what you're talking about:
[image: Thumbnail]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699128.aspx